# Changing value when posting to anotherAPI

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing an API Endpoint that will post to an external API, and I am unsure about the datatype to use for my viewModel

I have tried various ways of manipulating the ViewModel and JsonObject, but I currently have no progress to show to be closer to the desired result
This is running on .NET Core 2, web api project.

The class I have created to hold the data:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int AccountIds { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

The JSON the external API expects:

```
{
    "AccountIDs": [4],
    "Title":"value",
    "Category": "value"
}
```

When I try to POST that to my API I get the following error:

````
    "": [
        "JsonToken EndArray is not valid for closing JsonType Object. Path '', line 2, position 18."
    ],
    "AccountIDs": [
        "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'AccountIDs', line 2, position 16."
    ]
}```
````

Comment: in the JSON `AccountIds` is an array. update viewmodel `public int[] AccountIds { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AccountIDs` property of the external API expects an array of integers (`"AccountIDs": [4]`). So declare your model as such:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int[] AccountIDs { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I figured this out just moments before reading your post, but you are correct. Thanks for answering.